# PHP: blank page but no error when confronting NULL value in a function

Tags: php

No error in log of Apache...
This is my function:

```
function feedback($type,$message,$link=NULL) {
    if ( (isset($_POST['ajaxFeedback'])) && ($_POST['ajaxFeedback']==true) ) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-'.$type.'">';
            echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['typeMessage']    = $type;
        $_SESSION['message']        = $message;
        if (isset($link)) {
            header('Location: '.LINK_ASSOLUTO.$link);
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

if i call it with

```
feedback('success','All queries OK',$link=NULL);
```

i obtain stop of execution of page (all rest of page will be blank). Also if I omit $link and if I pass $link without the "=NULL".

If I pass a link, e.g.

```
feedback('success','All queries OK','/index.php');
```

all works  (i've used this function in several codes).

Help me.. thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to do `feedback('success','All queries OK',$link=NULL);` if it defaults to that? Do `feedback('success','All queries OK');` instead.

Comment: Your code paths are confusing you. Your if() test does not consider **ANYTHING** of what you pass in as arguments. the if() results depend entirely on $_POST values. Note that `isset($null)` is FALSE, so your header() call never occurs if you don't pass in a $link, or explicitly pass in a null - your script will set two sessionv values and then simply exit.

Comment: @MarcB you did put me in right way. In effect that "exit" must be to stay in if (isset($link) piece of code... Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set a default in the call of a function only the declaration. You should either call:

```
feedback('success','All queries OK');
```

or

```
feedback('success','All queries OK',null);
```

Also if `$link` is `null` and `$_POST['ajaxFeedback']` is not set your code just sets session values. However I don't see where you are using `session_start()`